# Can't set selected option in dropdown with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've this simple dropdown:

```
<select ng-model="v" ng-options="valve.Brand + ' ' + valve.Model + ' ' + valve.Notes for valve in valves track by valve.ValveId">
    <option value="">--Valves--</option>
</select>
```

I'm also using a web service to retrieve data from database. This data contains the `ValveId` that it's the parameter (value) I would like to use to set as selected an option of my dropdown.

I've tried this way from my controller:

```
$scope.v = $scope.valves[data.ValveId];
```

But it is not working.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your **ng-options** by:

```
valve.ValveId as valve.Brand + ' ' + valve.Model + ' ' + valve.Notes for valve in valves
```

Notice the **as** key at the beginning, it tells which property should be used as the model value.

The model will now have the ID as the value. Therefore, you can now set it directly:

```
$scope.v = data.ValveId;
```